# Is it possible to compile a windows service with cygwin?

Tags: c++, c, windows-services, cygwin, daemon

I tried to compile my C++ daemon code from linux, with cygwin. It worked but not as a windows service. It's in processes list. How can I run it as a service? Or can I compile a windows service with cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cygrunsrv` is used to install and manage Cygwin-based Windows services.  Once you've installed that package, complete documentation is available in the  `/usr/share/doc/Cygwin/cygrunsrv.README` file.